# How to get a reference to Internet Explorer's window handle in .net

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com, com-interop

Basically I am trying to get the HWND of an instance of Internet Explorer that I have been automating in C#.

```
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
        IE.AddressBar = false;
        IE.MenuBar = false;
        IE.OnQuit += IE_OnQuit;
        IE.Visible = true;
        IE.Navigate2("www.bing.com");
```

I would like to get a reference to it's window handle for further manipulation, however the only example of how to do this is in C++ and I am not sure how to do something similar in C#. The Example the msdn gave is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752126(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting the HWND is as simple as:

```
IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr)IE.HWND;
```

Comment: Where did you see the HWND property?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Do you mean casting it to  SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass?

Comment: The InternetExplorer object implements the IWebBrowser2 interface, and that one has this property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127(v=vs.85).aspx